# Can this JSON file be built in R?

Tags: r, json, list

Working in R, I am having difficulty building a JSON file that I would use in an API call.

The required format for the JSON file can be seen here:

```
{
  "ReportRoutes": [
    {
      "Stops": [
        {
          "Coords": {
            "Lat": "42.124560",
            "Lon": "-76.124560"
        },
        {
          "Coords": {
            "Lat": "42.123120",
            "Lon": "-76.123120"
          },
    }
  ]
}
```

The input to the exercise is a dataframe like so:

```
Shipper_Latitude <- c(1,2,3,4)
Shipper_Longitude <- c(1,2,3,4)
Consignee_Latitude <- c(1,2,3,4)
Consignee_Longitude <- c(1,2,3,4)
r2 <- data.frame(Shipper_Latitude,Shipper_Longitude,Consignee_Latitude ,Consignee_Longitude )
```

The code below gets me close:

```
tempfuna <- function(Lat,Lon) {list(Coords = list(Lat = Lat,Lon = Lon))}
df_jsona <- mapply(FUN = tempfuna,Lat = r2$Shipper_Latitude, Lon = r2$Shipper_Longitude)
df_jsona <- lapply(df_jsona, function(x) {list(Coords = x)})
        
tempfunb <- function(Lat,Lon) {list(Coords = list(Lat = Lat,Lon = Lon))}
df_jsonb <- mapply(FUN = tempfunb,Lat = r2$Consignee_Latitude, Lon = r2$Consignee_Longitude)
df_jsonb <- lapply(df_jsonb, function(x) {list(Coords = x)})
        
tempfunc <- function(A,B) {list(ReportRoutes = list(Stops = list(A,B)))}
df_jsonc <- mapply(FUN = tempfunc,A = df_jsona, B = df_jsonb)
        
post_body <- list(ReportRoutes = df_jsonc)
```

The only issue is that ReportRoutes is a named list rather than an unnamed list.

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been editing JSON files in R for a while and the best workflow for me is importing files as lists, editing and exporting. I rarely treat them as dataframes. Thus, I would have solved your problem like this:

```
# setup environment
library(jsonlite)
# build data
df = data.frame(
  Shipper_Latitude = c(1,2,3,4),
  Shipper_Longitude = c(1,2,3,4),
  Consignee_Latitude = c(1,2,3,4),
  Consignee_Longitude = c(1,2,3,4)
)
# define function to set coordinates
SetCoords = function(lat, long) list(Coords = list(Lat = lat, Long = long))

# define function to append a new stop
DefStops = function(lat1, long1, lat2, long2) {
    list(Stops = mapply(SetCoords, c(lat1, lat2), c(long1, long2),
                        SIMPLIFY = FALSE))
}
# apply functions to build the json file
routes_report =
    list(ReportRoutes = mapply(DefStops, df[[1]], df[[2]],
                               df[[3]], df[[4]], SIMPLIFY = FALSE))
# write json file
write_json(routes_report, '~/routes_report.json',
           auto_unbox = TRUE, pretty = TRUE)
```

Here is the output:

```
{
  "ReportRoutes": [
    {
      "Stops": [
        {
          "Coords": {
            "Lat": 1,
            "Long": 1
          }
        },
        {
          "Coords": {
            "Lat": 1,
            "Long": 1
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "Stops": [
        {
          "Coords": {
            "Lat": 2,
            "Long": 2
          }
        },
        {
          "Coords": {
            "Lat": 2,
            "Long": 2
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "Stops": [
        {
          "Coords": {
            "Lat": 3,
            "Long": 3
          }
        },
        {
          "Coords": {
            "Lat": 3,
            "Long": 3
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "Stops": [
        {
          "Coords": {
            "Lat": 4,
            "Long": 4
          }
        },
        {
          "Coords": {
            "Lat": 4,
            "Long": 4
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Let me know if it is what you are looking for.

Comment: Also works perfectly!   And also I think more intuitive than the approach I had been taking.

Comment: That's amazing. Good luck @dkent!

Answer (score 1):

> The only issue is that ReportRoutes is a named list rather than an unnamed list. Is there a way to fix this?

```
## change this line
post_body <- list(ReportRoutes = df_jsonc)
## to this
post_body <- list(ReportRoutes = unname(df_jsonc))
```